# Java, create and edit a Graphics Object for Panel?

Tags: java, graphics, panel, draw

I have the following task for my school in Java:

Create a GUI window with your own graphic. This graphic should be created in a separate JPanel class and drawn using the draw and fill methods of the java.awt.Graphics class (e.g. a house with a garden, a car, ...). The graphic should contain at least 5 different types of graphics (rectangle, oval, ...), at least one polygon (draw or fillPolygon (polygon p) method) and an arc (draw or fillArc method (int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle)). The graphic should also contain at least 10 drawing elements and consist of at least 4 different colors.

But I don´t know how to use the class Graphics, so I don´t know how to create a Grahpics object and edit it. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions on this site are expected to be written in English. Please edit your question and translate it into English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use graphics with a JPanel;

```
class exampleclass extends JPanel {
    exampleClass() {
       ...
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        ...your code here...
    }

}
```

For more information, look at; https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

You can call paint method with, `repaint();`

Comment: How do I use method paint(Graphics g)? If I try do do: paint(Graphics g1 = new Graphics()), I get an error :/ so the problem is I can´t create a Graphics Object

Comment: @AirKrypton Because, you mustn't create a new Graphics instance. This method already calls with graphics. You can use 'g' without create a new instance. Also you can't define a variable like that.

Comment: Oh thank you. But how do I call method paint if I hadn´t already created the object for parameter?

Comment: @AirKrypton You're welcome. You can call repaint() method always, you don't need to create parameter. It will always create a Graphics instance for you. If it helped, please mark as solution.

Comment: Yea I´ll do. But the method paint doesn´t return anything, so should I replace the void to Graphics so that I can add the Graphics object to the Panel?

Comment: @AirKrypton Paint void doesn't return anything, it's just painting the JPanel, you can use JPanel anywhere. That must be void.

Comment: Oh so I just have to create a JPanel object, edit it with the methods of Graphics and can add it to my Frame?

Comment: @AirKrypton Yes, you can paint your JPanel with paint(Graphics g) method. And you can add your JPanel to your Frame.

Comment: damn, I tried using method paint(Graphics g) in a constructor, I have tried "this.paint (g);" and "this.paint(Graphics g);" but I get an error with both

Comment: @AirKrypton You must use repaint().

Comment: And Java will use my @Override method called "paint(Graphics g)" if I use method "repaint()"?

Comment: Yes, when you call repaint, your paint method is calling with a new graphics instance.

Comment: @camickr Correct now?

Comment: Downvote removed. @AirKrypton - custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(…)`.  Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.